# how can i grab the reqnum from the string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table(pf1) with a column(comment) that has data. I need to grab the ReqNumber.

Row example

```
  CLIA::;ReqNum:1234567890:;PrfLab::;LabDep::;CtrlId::; Auth:NOT REQUIRED:
```

i need to get 1234567890 in a seperate column.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the datatype of the `comment` column?

Comment: @EricBrandt Varchar(max)

Comment: You should give it a try with string split on ';' and then on ':'

Comment: @KeithL SQL Server 2008 does not support string_split. Sorry should of included my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a lot of overkill here for this requirement. If it's as simple as grabbing the first 10 digits in the string you could do this:

**When reqnum is always 10 digits:**

```
SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@string,f.Pos,10)
FROM  (VALUES(PATINDEX('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',10)+'%', @string))) AS f(Pos);
```

Using [NGrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) (useful for stuff like this and much more) you could do this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) ng.Token
FROM   samd.NGrams8K(@string,10) AS ng
WHERE  PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',ng.Token) = 0
ORDER BY ng.Position;
```

**Let's say reqnum is a variable length, such as 8-12 digits long:**

The first technique is simpler, the second is more efficient:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = 
  'CLIA::;ReqNum:1234567890:;PrfLab::;LabDep::;CtrlId::; Auth:NOT REQUIRED:';

-- Technique #1
SELECT      SUBSTRING(@string,MAX(f.Pos),MAX(n.Rng))
FROM        (VALUES(12),(11),(10),(9),(8))                                AS n(Rng)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',n.Rng)+'%', @string))) AS f(Pos)
WHERE       f.Pos > 0;

-- Technique #2 (Better)
SELECT SUBSTRING(ns.Txt,1,f2.Pos)
FROM   (VALUES(PATINDEX('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',8)+'%',@string))) AS f(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,f.Pos,12)))               AS ns(Txt)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',ns.Txt)-1))             AS f2(Pos)
```

**When reqnum is any length *and* assuming there is only one sequence of numbers in the string**

This solution uses N-Grams to split the string. You could use [delimitedSplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) for this.

```
SELECT TOP (1)
  ItemIndex = ng.Position+1,
  Item      = f.Item
FROM        samd.ngrams8k(@string,1)                                         AS ng
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(':',@string,ng.Position+1)))                   AS nxt(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,ng.Position+1,nxt.Pos-ng.Position-1))) AS f(Item)
WHERE       ng.Token = ':' AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',f.Item)<PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',f.Item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
declare @row as varchar(100)= 'CLIA::;ReqNum:1234567890:;PrfLab::;LabDep::;CtrlId::; Auth:NOT REQUIRED:'

select left(right(@row, len(@row)-charindex('ReqNum', @row) - len('ReqNum')),charindex(':',right(@row, len(@row)-charindex('ReqNum', @row) - len('ReqNum')))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
declare
    @comment varchar(max) = 'CLIA::;ReqNum:1234567890:;PrfLab::;LabDep::;CtrlId::; Auth:NOT REQUIRED:',
    @start varchar(max) = 'ReqNum:',
    @end varchar(max) = ':'

select
    @comment,
    case
        when
            charindex(@start, @comment) > 0 and
            charindex(@end, @comment, charindex(@start, @comment) + len(@start)) > 0 then
            substring(
                @comment,
                charindex(@start, @comment) + len(@start),
                charindex(@end, @comment, charindex(@start, @comment) + len(@start)) -
                charindex(@start, @comment) - len(@start)
            ) 
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Abusing the XML type could work. 
But I have no way to test it on a 2008 R2.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(CAST('<x>'+REPLACE(t.comment,':;','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML).query('x[contains(., "ReqNum:")]').value('.','varchar(20)'),8,12) AS ReqNum
FROM pf1 t
```